# Prove that if $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is an interval then $X$ is connected.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, connectedness

### **Prove that if $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is an interval then $X$ is connected.**

*I found this proof in a book but I really don't understand it, and I would like to know if someone could please explain.*

*The proof is as follows:*

*We have already seen that the open intervals of the line are connected. The others are also because, given any interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$, there is always a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(\mathbb{R})=I$. For example, if $I=[-1,+1]$ and we take $f(x)=\sin{x}$. For $I=(0,1]$, we take $f(x)=(1+x^{2})^{-1}$ and if $I=[0,+ \infty)$, we take $f(x)=x^{2}$. Each unopened interval is homeomorphic to one of these three, so it is connected.*

Comment: Do you agree that connectedness is a property which is invariant under homeomorphism?

Comment: Which part of the proof do you not understand?

Comment: @guidoar as well?

Comment: @EricWofsey I don't understand the fact that every unopened interval is homeomorphic to one of these three given examples, so they are connected.

Comment: There are two ingredients on the proof. The first one is: if $A$ and $B$ are homeomorphic, then $A$ is connected iff $B$ is. The second step is to note that *any* interval is homeomorphic to one of those examples. And those, in turn, are homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$ - which is connected - and thus they are connected.

Comment: @guidoar Okay. And when you talk about A and B you mean what?

Comment: In this context I meant $A$ and $B$ to be subsets of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @guidoar Ok, I understand, so I already have the first part since every homeomorphic set is a connected set. I would miss the second part

Comment: Okay, for the second part: first, convince yourself that the maps given are indeed isomorphisms. Maybe you have done this in class already. Secondly, let's do one of the many cases (the rest are all quite similar, and tedious, hence why this proof omits all calculations). Pick your favourite interval and I'll give you a homeomorphism to one of the above.

Comment: @guidoar ok, so I choose the interval $I = [0, + \infty)$ with $f(x) = x^{2}$

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. Do you want to see that *any* interval is homeomorphic to one of the ones cited; or that the maps claimed to be homeomorphisms are indeed homeo?

Comment: Has some theorem been stated that says that the image of a connected space under a continuous function is connected?

Comment: @guidoarI want to see that any interval is homeomorphic to one of the above

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, I have given that theorem

Comment: @taylorwey : So they're showing that every interval is the image of an open interval under some continuous function. Do you mean you don't understand how that was done?

Comment: @MichaelHardy I don't really understand your question, I just want to prove that if $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $X$ is an interval then this is connected

Comment: So what is it you don't understand in the proof? The proof shows that every interval is the image of an open interval under a continuous function. You have a theorem that says open intervals are connected, and another theorem that says the image of a connected space under a continuous function is connected. Therefore all that remains is to show that every interval is the union of an open interval under a continuous function. That is what the proof that you quote does.

Comment: You might want to include **your definition** of an interval, because in many real analysis texts an interval is defined to be a connected subset (in the topological sense) of the reals. My guess is that your definition of an interval is "connected in the linearly ordered set sense", and you want to prove each of these is connected in the topological sense.